# Nested object: Update all attributes with same names

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a quit complex object with multiple nested objects.
This object i want to copy and update all id attributes.

So this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "A",
  car: {
    id: 2,
    vendor: "xy"
    }
  ..
}
```

should become this:

```
{
  id: 6,
  name: "A",
  car: {
    id: 7,
    vendor: "xy"
    }
  ..
}
```

Is there a way to this in a short and generic way with JavaScript (TypeScript)?

**Update:**
What I did so far:

```
const a = new MyClass();
a.id = uuid();
a.name = "A"
a.car = new Car();
a.car.id = uuid();
a.car.vendor = "xy"

//copy a
const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

All I want to do is increase all ids in b by 5.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What is the logic you apply to the `id`? You want to add 5 to all of them?

Comment: what do you mean with *"copy"*?

Comment: Actually the ids are uuids and i want to generate for every id a new uuid (with uuid())

Comment: I made some clarification what i mean with copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the items in `b` and do two things. If it's an `id` property, change it (add 5). If it's an object, loop through and check both the same conditions (recursive function). Here's how you could do it:

```
function checkObject(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) { 
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && prop !== null) { 
            checkObject(obj[prop]);
        }
        else if (prop == "id") {
            obj[prop] += 5;
        }
    })
}
```

Then you'd call it like so:

```js
function checkObject(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) { 
        if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && prop !== null) { 
            checkObject(obj[prop]);
        }
        else if (prop == "id") {
            obj[prop] += 5;
        }
    })
}

var b = {
  id: 1,
  name: "A",
  car: {
id: 2,
vendor: "xy"
}
 }

checkObject(b);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Be aware that `typeof null === "object"`.

Comment: Ok Sam I think I've fixed it. trincot, I also know how to fix that.

Comment: Fixed it now Sam

Comment: I'm really sorry - I wrote this code a while ago for myself and have a few copy paste errors.

Comment: @JackBashford - yes, this now works as I'd expect, thanks for putting up with my many error checks, +1 for this solution as it's elegant and works well!

Comment: I am confused, @max, because you wrote in your question *"This object i want to **copy**"*, but this solution does not copy the object, it mutates it.

Comment: @trincot SamSwift didn't post the question - max did.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @JackBashford... updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that clones the original object into a new one where each `id` property receives a new value generated by a given `uuid` function:

```js
function assignId(data, uuid) {
    return Object(data) !== data ? data
        : Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(data).map( ([k, v]) =>
            ({ [k]: k === "id" ? uuid() : assignId(v, uuid) })
        ));
}

// Example use:
function uuid() {
    return uuid.next = (uuid.next || 1000) + 1;
}
const a = { id: 1, name: "A", car: { id: 2, vendor: "xy" } };
const b = assignId(a, uuid);
console.log(b);
```